# Create custom Exception handler and custom error template in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, exception, cakephp-2.0

I tried to create a new custom handler in cakephp . It was not working for me. I need to show custom messages to the user when he tries to access the url which are not accessible/restricted to him. Right now cake showing Internal Server Error, but I need to show custom messages with his accessible page link. I need to throw an exception in /Lib/...php

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom exception handler in cakephp 2.x see this link

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#create-your-own-exception-handler-with-exception-handler

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#using-a-custom-renderer-with-exception-renderer-to-handle-application-exceptions

You can change layout in beforeRender() of AppController

```
public function beforeRender(){
  if($this->name == 'CakeError'){
      $this->layout = 'error';
   }        
}
```